# Estoy intentando guardar filas de una factura con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero guardar los datos de varias filas con un solo id "orden_id" ejemplo:

[![filas se guardan con el mismos id][1]][1]

Este es el codigo que intento hacer para que funcione

```php
<?php

$lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['codigo']); $i++) {
    $sqlInsertItem =" INSERT INTO productos_factura (orden_id, codigo, cantidad, detalle, valorUnidad, valorTotal) VALUES ('".$lastInsertId."','".$_POST['codigo'][$i]."','".$_POST['cantidad'][$i]."', '".$_POST['detalle'][$i]."','".$_POST['valorUnidad'][$i]."', '".$_POST['valorTotal'][$i]."')";
}

?>
```

```
FORMATO DEL TABLA

CREATE TABLE `productos_factura` (
  `orden_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orden_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf32_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `detalle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf32_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valorUnidad` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `valorTotal` int(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_unicode_ci;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeSdp.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me a funcionado de la siguiente forma. Antes de cerrar el for,

escribí esto y funciono, ya que cada vez que completaba un ciclo, guardaba los datos en la tabla.

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlInsertItem);
```

el codigo seria:

```
<?php

// Hago una llamada a la ultima id creada dentro de mi base de datos
$lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['codigo']); $i++) {
    $sqlInsertItem ="
     INSERT INTO productos_factura (orden_id, codigo, cantidad, detalle, valorUnidad, valorTotal)
     VALUES ('".$lastInsertId."','".$_POST['codigo'][$i]."','".$_POST['cantidad'][$i]."', '".$_POST['detalle'][$i]."','".$_POST['valorUnidad'][$i]."', '".$_POST['valorTotal'][$i]."')";

     //este codigo registra en cada ciclo la información en la tabla productos_factura
     mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlInsertItem);
}

?>
```

Comment: Que bueno tengas la solución, por favor considera que si esta es la respuesta la marques como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Creo que encontré tu problema, al momento de crear la tabla el campo orden_item_id debe ir de la siguiente forma

```
'orden_item_id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Para que el id de los valores que estas ingresando se vaya actualizando a medida que vas ingresando los datos, el campo id de la tabla debe tener un autoincrementable si es que no lo ingresaras de forma manual.

Comment: mira la imagen de la tabla en MySQL como la tengo (https://imgur.com/wAHcch0)

Comment: @Fabiantric me podrias adjuntar una imagen de tu for completo por favor, o es tal cual como lo escribiste? O si puede ser tu archivo php completo mucho mejor.

Answer (score 0):

¿La conexión a la base de datos para la inserción?

```
<?php

$lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['codigo']); $i++) {
    $sqlInsertItem = ($conexion, " INSERT INTO productos_factura (orden_id, codigo, cantidad, detalle, valorUnidad, valorTotal) VALUES ('".$lastInsertId."','".$_POST['codigo'][$i]."','".$_POST['cantidad'][$i]."', '".$_POST['detalle'][$i]."','".$_POST['valorUnidad'][$i]."', '".$_POST['valorTotal'][$i]."')");
}
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: No se entiende tu aporte, es una pregunta o la solución?

Comment: Ambas cosas, le pregunto por la conexión si la tiene en otro sitio y no la ha copiado, y si no la tiene, se la he aplicado a su código.

Comment: Considera leer [answer], pues tu aporte no es claro, por otro lado la zona de respuestas no es el espacio adecuado para exponer dudas o comentarios